# How to fully stop IIS using command line / bat file

Tags: batch-file, iis, command-line

I used to stop the IIS using "iisreset /stop" or "iisreset /start" but I noticed that it only stops everything under "Application Pools", not the server itself (my basis is when i click the server tab, I could see the "Stop" button is still enabled). Are there other commands to fully stop it? (Need to stop the whole thing since there are files I cannot modify due to IIS still running, need it to be a command for automation purposes)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you've tried yourself and how it has failed otherwise you're requesting code or using StackOverflow as a live search engine, _which is off-topic_. Did you try `Net Stop Iisadmin /Y` to stop it and it's dependent services. Starting it using `Net Start` however may mean having  to first start those dependent services, e.g. `Net Start Msftpsvc`, `Net Start Nntpsvc`, `Net Start Smtpsvc`, `Net Start W3svc` and `Net Start Iisadmin`. You may alternatively use `sc.exe`, enter `SC /?` at the command prompt for help and usage information.

Answer (score 4):

You need to stop windows service "World Wide Web Publishing Service". 
Just run this  in command prompt with Admin privileges

```
net stop "W3SVC"
```